# Parsing nested JSON into structs

Tags: solidity, struct

I need to store the following JSON object in a struct.

```
{ 
   "id":"ea6d69b3-f1",
   "type":"ofoo",
   "channel":"website",
   "funding":[ 
      { 
         "type":"xxx",
         "amount":"1",
         "cohort":"xxx",
         "promotion":"53a16648-07"
      },
      {
        "type":"xxx",
         "amount":"1",
         "cohort":"conl",
         "promotion":"53a16648-3"
      } 
   ],
   "createdAt":"2019-11-16T01:30:28.538789516Z",
   "totalAmount":"2" // Total amount of sum of amounts in funding tag
}
```

I know storing it as a simple nested struct is trivial, but having to add `funding.amount + funding.amount` to arrive at `totalamount`.

So far, I have tried this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.11;
contract Analytics {
  struct Field {
    string typeOfFunding; // type is a reserved word in solidity https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/miscellaneous.html#reserved-keywords
    uint amount;
    string cohort;
    string promotion;
  }
  struct Entry {
    string typeofEntry; // lack of better terminology
    string channel;
    Field[] funding;
    string createdAt;
    uint totalAmount;
  }
  mapping(string => Entry) entries;


  function updateEntry (string memory id,
                        string memory _typeOfEntry,
                        string memory _channel,
                        Field[]  _funding,
                        string memory _createdAt) public
                        returns (bool sucess)
  {
    Entry storage e = entries[id];
    e.typeofEntry = _typeOfEntry;
    e.channel = _channel;
    // e.funding = _funding;
    // e.funding = "0";
    // e.funding.push(_funding);
    e.createdAt = _createdAt;
    // e.totalAmount = updateFunding(_funding);
    return true;
  }

  function updateFunding(string memory id,  Field[]  _fundingP) private view returns (Field[] _funding)
  {
    Field[] memory funding;
    Field[] memory amount;

    for _fundingP.amount 
    {
      funding.push(_funding.amount)
    }
  }
```

I would appreciate pointers on this issue

Comment: You might wanna consider rephrasing your question in order to make it more readable. I, for one, have read it several times and "got lost" somewhere along the way. Why is "having to add funding.amount + funding.amount to arrive at totalamount" a problem (i.e., since when did adding two values become a problem)? Furthermore, there is no mentioning of any other problem, just a piece of code which doesn't even seem fully related to the initial description (e.g., why do you need a mapping in order to represent a JSON structure?), followed by "I would appreciate pointers on this issue".

Comment: Thanks!! will do ASAP @goodvibration